# php Slim framework - passing parameter to closure

Tags: php, closures, slim

I am trying to study the code for Slim framework. In the constructor for Slim class, $c is passed to the closure (for instance, when storing/setting the request/response object in the container):

```
 public function __construct(array $userSettings = array())
    {
        // Setup IoC container
        $this->container = new \Slim\Helper\Set();
        $this->container['settings'] = array_merge(static::getDefaultSettings(), $userSettings);

        // Default request
        $this->container->singleton('request', function ($c) {
          return new \Slim\Http\Request($c['environment']);
        });

        // Default response
        $this->container->singleton('response', function ($c) {
          return new \Slim\Http\Response();
        });
```

But $c is not defined/declared anywhere prior to this statement, so how does it work? I started to trace everything from the beginning and I can't find $c anywhere prior to it being used in this manner.

Answer (score 2):

$c is a parameter of the closure function. Imagine you had a function by itself:

```
function myFunction($c) {
    echo $c;
}
```

In the case of a closure, you can store an anonymous function in a variable:

```
$someFunction = function ($c) {
    echo $c;
}
$someFunction("hello world");
```

So instead of directly storing the closure into the variable, the code above is passing the anonymous function as a parameter to $this->container->singleton(). So $c is not created until the closure is called. The singleton method stores this in a variable called $value, so if that function ran:

```
$value(array('environment'=>'test'));
```

$c would now contain array('environment'=>'test')

Slim also uses the __get() __set() magic methods quite a bit, so from the example code you set, within the Slim class, one could call:

```
$request = $this->container->request(array('environment'=>'test'));
```

The container is of class Slim\Helper\Set. Since this doesn't have a request method, this would call the container's __get() method. It would look up the stored method configured above for 'request' and pass the array in as $c

Comment: Yes, I understand that an anonymous function can be stored in a variable.  And I can also see that the anonymous function is being passed as a parameter to the singleton method. But I still don't understand where the $c is coming from. You're saying it's not created until closure is called.. So when it's created, it equates to what? What is the $c variable storing? Thanks!

Comment: When the anonymous function is called, that's when the value of $c is assigned. In other words in order to call the closure, you would need to pass it the value you want to assign to $c (see end of edited answer)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and get my head around it. I tried to look up some literature, but not knowing what's the term that I should be searching for, I couldn't find something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think khartnett gave a perfect answer. To make it clearer for you, an example.

When you define a function, you are only describing how it works. You are not setting any specific values. For example, when I write:

```
function sum($a, $b) {    
    return $a + $b;
}
```

I am not saying what the values of `$a` and `$b` are here. I am just describing what I am doing with these variables to calculate a result. It is not until I *call* this function that I'm working with actual values:

```
sum(3, 4); // returns 7
```

In your question, the `$c` variable is like the `$a` and `$b` variable.

Like khartnett showed in his answer, it works like this:

```
// Definition time
$someFunction = function ($c) {
    echo $c;
}

// Calling time
$someFunction("hello world");
```

It is not until calling time that `$c` gets its value (in this example, the value is "hello world").

Answer (score 0):

The `$c` is a reference to the container itself - so that any dependencies will be automatically resolved when invoked.

So using for example the request object:

```
    // Default request
    $this->container->singleton('request', function ($c) {
        return new \Slim\Http\Request($c['environment']);
    });
```

Looking at the `Request` constructor you will see that it expects an instance of `Environment`, which we just told the container should be available already using the key 'environment'.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will lay in `$app->run()`:
`$this->container->get("service_name")` then in `get()` method `offsetGet($id)`

```
public function offsetGet($id)
    {
        if (!isset($this->keys[$id])) {
            throw new UnknownIdentifierException($id);
        }

        if (
            isset($this->raw[$id])
            || !\is_object($this->values[$id])
            || isset($this->protected[$this->values[$id]])
            || !\method_exists($this->values[$id], '__invoke')
        ) {
            return $this->values[$id];
        }

        if (isset($this->factories[$this->values[$id]])) {
            return $this->values[$id]($this);
        }

        $raw = $this->values[$id];
        $val = $this->values[$id] = $raw($this); // THIS LINE CALLS THE CONTAINER ITSELF
        $this->raw[$id] = $raw;

        $this->frozen[$id] = true;

        return $val;
    }
```

Pimple Container functioning it's a bit more complicated due to the fact:
 Allowing any PHP callable leads to difficult to debug problems
 as function names (strings) are callable (creating a function with
 the same name as an existing parameter would break your container)
 So unique identifiers are introduced.

Here is a simple implementation of ServiceContainer `get()` method inside the `ServiceContainer class`:

```
public function get($serviceName)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($serviceName, $this->container)) {
            throw new \http\Exception\InvalidArgumentException("Service not found!");
        }
        $service = $this->container[$serviceName];
        if (is_callable($service)) {
            $this->container[$serviceName] = $service = $service($this);
 // $this (aka ServiceContainer) will be passed as parameter to Closures
        }
        return $service;
    }
```

Hope it clarifies the question, have a nice day!